# jsp + php + asp.net + python in one site?

Tags: php, asp.net, python, jsp, webserver

I have a question: can I mix jsp, php, asp.net and python in one site?

For example:

```
www.mysite.com/customer.html <-- this page is written by jsp
www.mysite.com/mycart.html <-- this page is written by php
www.mysite.com/login.html <-- this page is written by asp.net
www.mysite.com/admin.html <-- this page is written by python
```

I use ".html" as I don't want other know what technology I am using.

I am facing some problems:

1. What web server can hold all these technologies?
2. How can they share session?

Or just simply tell me this is impossible...

Thanks

Comment: I just want to try some new. :D And I am interested in that as a web developer, why we are limited in language.

Comment: You are not limited by anything, but bluntly said - it would be really pointless to mix these technologies. I mean, you'd do 1 page in java, another in python, another in php.. to what point? It has absolutely no sense. If you want to do it to satisfy your personal curiosity - that's fine, you CAN do it if you set up your web server properly so it knows what to call for each of the pages. However, no one in the world would do this for a commercial project because it's a waste of time and resources. Not to mention it's not scalable at all.

Comment: I find this question interesting for one reason. If you have your server configured to support all these languages then your development station is pretty much set. How annoying is it to want to try something out in ASP.net but not having a server available?

Comment: Mixing them together is **NOT** pointless. Reason 1: programmers involvement: if a technology is mixing technologies, Java/.NET/PHP/Python programmers are able to involve in it. Reason 2: Use advantages for all languages/technologies: every language/technology has advantages, however, the fact is that we **forced** to make a choice between technologies. Once we make a choice on a technology, it is hard to change it.

Comment: That's like saying this. If I write a book in several different languages, a lot of people can read different parts of it.

Comment: That's the reason Harry Potter is so popular around the whole world. Think big think more and think outside!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot share a session unless there is one module (for apache or something) that encompasses all of these technologies properly.

If this doesn't bother you, then, just configure your webserver to handle all of the file endings and such.

Answer (score 0):

Speaking from my experience, I suppose all web servers supports these languages. You just have to install their parsers/modules and configure your web server to use them. You'd have to give your pages different suffixes though, so that your web server will know what to do with the files.

```
www.mysite.com/customer.jsp
www.mysite.com/mycart.php
www.mysite.com/login.aspx
www.mysite.com/admin.py
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always generate a random key like `a234feg321de32` for the session, store it into your db for each user, and send it in the GET or POST variables, then check it with a select query. This would work even if you pushed your test further and switched from one server to another.

Answer (score 0):

I like your idea. With nginx you can easily redirect requests to the different applications in whatever way you prefer. When it comes to session sharing (and all kinds of data sharing) the easiest and safest way would be to communicate via a database. Problem is, you would have to implement your own session management solution in all different systems.